# How to convert from utf-16 to utf-32 on Linux with std library?

Tags: c++, gcc, unicode, utf-16

On MSVC converting utf-16 to utf-32 is easy - with C11's **codecvt_utf16** locale facet. But in GCC (gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2) seemingly this new feature hasn't been implemented yet. Is there a way to perform such conversion on Linux without iconv (preferrably using conversion tools of std library)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use iconv?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to implement it yourself?

Comment: Well, the reason is that if this can be done with std - why to invent the wheel?

Comment: Because your std doesn't implement it :-)

Comment: The codecvt_utf16 is the only way in std for such conversion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Decoding UTF-16 into UTF-32 is extremely easy.

You may want to detect at compile time the libc version you're using, and deploy your conversion routine if you detect a broken libc (without the functions you need).

Inputs:

- a pointer to the source UTF-16 data (`char16_t *`, `ushort *`, -- for convenience `UTF16 *`);
- its size;
- a pointer to the UTF-32 data (`char32_t *`, `uint *` -- for convenience `UTF32 *`).

Code looks like:

```
void convert_utf16_to_utf32(const UTF16 *input, 
                            size_t input_size, 
                            UTF32 *output) 
{
    const UTF16 * const end = input + input_size;
    while (input < end) {
        const UTF16 uc = *input++;
        if (!is_surrogate(uc)) {
            *output++ = uc; 
        } else {
            if (is_high_surrogate(uc) && input < end && is_low_surrogate(*input))
                *output++ = surrogate_to_utf32(uc, *input++);
            else
                // ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

Error handling is left. You might want to insert a `U+FFFD`¹ into the stream and keep on going, or just bail out, really up to you. The auxiliary functions are trivial:

```
int is_surrogate(UTF16 uc) { return (uc - 0xd800u) < 2048u; }
int is_high_surrogate(UTF16 uc) { return (uc & 0xfffffc00) == 0xd800; }
int is_low_surrogate(UTF16 uc) { return (uc & 0xfffffc00) == 0xdc00; }

UTF32 surrogate_to_utf32(UTF16 high, UTF16 low) { 
    return (high << 10) + low - 0x35fdc00; 
}
```

---

¹ Cf. Unicode:

- [§ 3.9 Unicode Encoding Forms (Best Practices for Using U+FFFD)](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch03.pdf)
- [§ 5.22 Best Practice for U+FFFD Substitution](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode13.0.0/ch05.pdf)

² Also consider that the `!is_surrogate(uc)` branch is by far the most common (as well the non-error path in the second if), you might want to optimize that with `__builtin_expect` or similar.

Comment: Almost the same amount of code that is required for using codecvt_utf16.

Comment: can you please explain the is_xx_surrogate methods?

Comment: Thanks! But what about the 0000..D7FF range? It seems like the is_surrogate function does not count it.

Comment: Uhm, re-reading the code *FIVE YEARS LATER*, I think I have made a typo in `is_surrogate`. I was thinking about using unsigned arithmetic, not signed.

Comment: I think it should be fixed now.

Comment: Mr. Peppe, yes, it works now! Thank you very much! Is it possible to use your code in proprietary projects?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's so simple I can hardly claim copyright on that. Pretty sure it's also found everywhere...

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo! I will be putting this in production code, although adding error checking.