# how can I convert wstring to u16string?

Tags: c++, winapi, utf-16, wstring, valueconverter

I want to convert `wstring` to `u16string` in C++.

I can convert `wstring` to string, or reverse. But I don't know how convert to `u16string`.

```
u16string CTextConverter::convertWstring2U16(wstring str)

{

        int iSize;
        u16string szDest[256] = {};
        memset(szDest, 0, 256);
        iSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, NULL, str.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,0,0);

        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, NULL, str.c_str(), -1, szDest, iSize,0,0);
        u16string s16 = szDest;
        return s16;
}
```

Error in WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, NULL, str.c_str(), -1, szDest, iSize,0,0);'s `szDest`. Cause of `u16string` can't use with `LPSTR`.

How can I fix this code?

Comment: A little suggestion, change parameter of your function to `const wstring& str` to avoid the unneccessary copying.

Comment: You may consider accepting the [answer of @Davislor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42743775/7571258) instead. Although my answer may be good enough for you, Davislor's answer is much more comprehensive and may help other people looking for a platform-independent solution. Thanks!

Comment: @zett42 That’s very kind and professional of you.

Comment: @zett42 I can’t believe I went back to this, but there is in fact a standard method to do this, and it works in `clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++`, and in Visual C++ 19 with some workarounds. The libstdc++ library is just bugged (as of March ’17).  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a **platform-independent** solution see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42743775/7571258).

If you need a solution only for the **Windows platform**, the following code will be sufficient:

```cpp
std::wstring wstr( L"foo" );
std::u16string u16str( wstr.begin(), wstr.end() );
```

On the Windows platform, a `std::wstring` is interchangeable with `std::u16string` because `sizeof(wstring::value_type) == sizeof(u16string::value_type)` and both are UTF-16 (little endian) encoded.

```cpp
wstring::value_type = wchar_t
u16string::value_type = char16_t
```

The only difference is that `wchar_t` is signed, whereas `char16_t` is unsigned. So you only have to do sign conversion, which can be performed by using the `u16string` constructor that takes an iterator pair as arguments. This constructor will implicitly convert `wchar_t` to `char16_t`.

Full example console application:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    static_assert( sizeof(std::wstring::value_type) == sizeof(std::u16string::value_type),
        "std::wstring and std::u16string are expected to have the same character size" );
   
    std::wstring wstr( L"foo" );
    std::u16string u16str( wstr.begin(), wstr.end() );
   
    // The u16string constructor performs an implicit conversion like:
    wchar_t wch = L'A';
    char16_t ch16 = wch;
   
    // Need to reinterpret_cast because char16_t const* is not implicitly convertible
    // to LPCWSTR (aka wchar_t const*).
    ::MessageBoxW( 0, reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>( u16str.c_str() ), L"test", 0 );
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is where I was going to say, this is not portable code because, on many implementations, a `wstring` is UCS-4, not UTF-16, and the conversion fails for characters from U+10000 to U+10FFFF. However, after writing a bunch of test code, what I discovered is that the standard library does not implement conversion from UCS-4 or `wchar_t` to UTF-16 directly (although the hook is there), but only round-trip conversion through UTF-8. Nobody would actually do that. Even so, this code will fail on some implementations.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks for pointing that out! I was aware of that, that's why I've put the `static_assert` in there. As OP tagged question with "winapi" I thought the trivial conversion was sufficient. But it's useful to have an answer with platform-independent code too.

Comment: There is a [better answer for none Windows platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23920015/1387438).

Comment: For others: the encoded bytes order (endianness) of the basic types `char16_t` depends on the system's endianness. By saying "on the windows platform , `std::wstring` and `u16string` are both UTF-16 (little endian) encoded", it indicates the fact that most windows are installed on x86 (little endian).

Comment: Why don't just `u16string ustr=(char16_t*)a_wstring.c_str()` on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

#### Update

I had thought the standard version did not work, but in fact this was simply due to bugs in the Visual C++ and libstdc++ 3.4.21 runtime libraries.  It does work with `clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++`.  Here is a version that tests whether the standard method works on your compiler:

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::exit;
using std::memcmp;
using std::size_t;

using std::wcout;

#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
// Windows needs a little non-standard magic for this to work.
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#endif

using std::size_t;

void init_locale(void)
// Does magic so that wcout can work.
{
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
  // Windows needs a little non-standard magic.
  constexpr char cp_utf16le[] = ".1200";
  setlocale( LC_ALL, cp_utf16le );
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT );
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  constexpr char locale_name[] = "";
  std::locale::global(std::locale(locale_name));
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
#endif
}

int main(void)
{
  constexpr char16_t msg_utf16[] = u"¡Hola, mundo! \U0001F600"; // Shouldn't assume endianness.
  constexpr wchar_t msg_w[] = L"¡Hola, mundo! \U0001F600";
  constexpr char32_t msg_utf32[] = U"¡Hola, mundo! \U0001F600";
  constexpr char msg_utf8[] = u8"¡Hola, mundo! \U0001F600";

  init_locale();

  const std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x1FFFF, std::little_endian> converter_w;
  const size_t max_len = sizeof(msg_utf16);
  std::vector<char> out(max_len);
  std::mbstate_t state;
  const wchar_t* from_w = nullptr;
  char* to_next = nullptr;

  converter_w.out( state, msg_w, msg_w+sizeof(msg_w)/sizeof(wchar_t), from_w, out.data(), out.data() + out.size(), to_next );


  if (memcmp( msg_utf8, out.data(), sizeof(msg_utf8) ) == 0 ) {
    wcout << L"std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t> converts to UTF-8, not UTF-16!" << endl;
  } else if ( memcmp( msg_utf16, out.data(), max_len ) != 0 ) {
    wcout << L"std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t> conversion not equal!" << endl;
  } else {
    wcout << L"std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t> conversion is correct." << endl;
  }
  out.clear();
  out.resize(max_len);

  const std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t, 0x1FFFF, std::little_endian> converter_u32;
  const char32_t* from_u32 = nullptr;
  converter_u32.out( state, msg_utf32, msg_utf32+sizeof(msg_utf32)/sizeof(char32_t), from_u32, out.data(), out.data() + out.size(), to_next );

  if ( memcmp( msg_utf16, out.data(), max_len ) != 0 ) {
    wcout << L"std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t> conversion not equal!" << endl;
  } else {
    wcout << L"std::codecvt_utf16<char32_t> conversion is correct." << endl;
  }

  wcout << msg_w << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Previous

A bit late to the game, but here’s a version that additionally checks whether `wchar_t` is 32-bits (as it is on Linux), and if so, performs surrogate-pair conversion.  I recommend saving this source as UTF-8 with a BOM.  [Here is a link to it on ideone.](https://ideone.com/0ZCVqn)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cwctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
// Windows needs a little non-standard magic for this to work.
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#endif

using std::size_t;

void init_locale(void)
// Does magic so that wcout can work.
{
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
  // Windows needs a little non-standard magic.
  constexpr char cp_utf16le[] = ".1200";
  setlocale( LC_ALL, cp_utf16le );
  _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT );
#else
  // The correct locale name may vary by OS, e.g., "en_US.utf8".
  constexpr char locale_name[] = "";
  std::locale::global(std::locale(locale_name));
  std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
#endif
}

std::u16string make_u16string( const std::wstring& ws )
/* Creates a UTF-16 string from a wide-character string.  Any wide characters
 * outside the allowed range of UTF-16 are mapped to the sentinel value U+FFFD,
 * per the Unicode documentation. (http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html
 * retrieved 12 March 2017.) Unpaired surrogates in ws are also converted to
 * sentinel values.  Noncharacters, however, are left intact.  As a fallback,
 * if wide characters are the same size as char16_t, this does a more trivial
 * construction using that implicit conversion.
 */
{
  /* We assume that, if this test passes, a wide-character string is already
   * UTF-16, or at least converts to it implicitly without needing surrogate
   * pairs.
   */
  if ( sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(char16_t) ) {
    return std::u16string( ws.begin(), ws.end() );
  } else {
    /* The conversion from UTF-32 to UTF-16 might possibly require surrogates.
     * A surrogate pair suffices to represent all wide characters, because all
     * characters outside the range will be mapped to the sentinel value
     * U+FFFD.  Add one character for the terminating NUL.
     */
    const size_t max_len = 2 * ws.length() + 1;
    // Our temporary UTF-16 string.
    std::u16string result;

    result.reserve(max_len);

    for ( const wchar_t& wc : ws ) {
      const std::wint_t chr = wc;

      if ( chr < 0 || chr > 0x10FFFF || (chr >= 0xD800 && chr <= 0xDFFF) ) {
        // Invalid code point.  Replace with sentinel, per Unicode standard:
        constexpr char16_t sentinel = u'\uFFFD';
        result.push_back(sentinel);
      } else if ( chr < 0x10000UL ) { // In the BMP.
        result.push_back(static_cast<char16_t>(wc));
      } else {
        const char16_t leading = static_cast<char16_t>( 
          ((chr-0x10000UL) / 0x400U) + 0xD800U );
        const char16_t trailing = static_cast<char16_t>( 
          ((chr-0x10000UL) % 0x400U) + 0xDC00U );

        result.append({leading, trailing});
      } // end if
    } // end for

   /* The returned string is shrunken to fit, which might not be the Right
    * Thing if there is more to be added to the string.
    */
    result.shrink_to_fit();

    // We depend here on the compiler to optimize the move constructor.
    return result;
  } // end if
  // Not reached.
}

int main(void)
{
  static const std::wstring wtest(L"☪☮∈✡℩☯✝ \U0001F644");
  static const std::u16string u16test(u"☪☮∈✡℩☯✝ \U0001F644");
  const std::u16string converted = make_u16string(wtest);

  init_locale();

  std::wcout << L"sizeof(wchar_t) == " << sizeof(wchar_t) << L".\n";

  for( size_t i = 0; i <= u16test.length(); ++i ) {
    if ( u16test[i] != converted[i] ) {
      std::wcout << std::hex << std::showbase
                 << std::right << std::setfill(L'0')
                 << std::setw(4) << (unsigned)converted[i] << L" ≠ "
                 << std::setw(4) << (unsigned)u16test[i] << L" at "
                 << i << L'.' << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } // end if
  } // end for

  std::wcout << wtest << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Footnote

Since someone asked: The reason I suggest UTF-8 with BOM is that some compilers, including MSVC 2015, will assume a source file is encoded according to the current code page unless there is a BOM or you specify an encoding on the command line.  No encoding works on all toolchains, unfortunately, but every tool I’ve used that’s modern enough to support C++14 also understands the BOM.

Comment: I suggest to include the link in your post, so it won't get buried in the comments. I would propably do `result.reserve(ws.length())` instead of `2  *ws.length() + 1` because surrogates are quite rare and thus we could avoid reallocation in the common case.

Comment: Thanks.  I’ve edited the code a lot since you posted that; among other improvements, it now handles invalid codepoints by mapping them to a sentinel value instead of throwing an assertion.  New link (also added to the post): https://ideone.com/nrCowQ

Comment: @zett42 Go to Twitter and you’ll find plenty of strings that are the worst-case scenario, entirely composed of characters outside the BMP.  Kids these days and their emoji.

Comment: Confirmed to work with MSVC++2017 (if you select a proper font in the console, it shows most characters except for the "face with rolling eyes" \U0001F644).

Answer (score 0):

```
- To convert CString to std:wstring and string

    string CString2string(CString str)
    {
        int bufLen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCTSTR)str, -1, NULL, 0, NULL,NULL);
        char *buf = new char[bufLen];
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCTSTR)str, -1, buf, bufLen, NULL, NULL);
        string sRet(buf);
        delete[] buf;
        return sRet;
    }
    CString strFileName = "test.txt";
    wstring wFileName(strFileName.GetBuffer());
    strFileName.ReleaseBuffer();
    string sFileName = CString2string(strFileName);

- To convert string to CString

    CString string2CString(string s)
    {
        int bufLen = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
        WCHAR *buf = new WCHAR[bufLen];
        MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), -1, buf, bufLen);
        CString strRet(buf);
        delete[] buf;
        return strRet;
    }
    string sFileName = "test.txt";
    CString strFileName = string2CString(sFileName);
```