# Conversion from wstring to u16string and back (standard conform) in C++17 / C++20

Tags: c++, c++17, utf-16, wstring, utf-32

My main platform is Windows which is the reason why I use internally UTF-16 (mostly BMP strings).
I would like to use console output for these strings.

Unfortunately there is no `std::u16cout` or `std::u8cout` so I need to use `std::wcout`. Therefore I must convert my u16strings to wstrings - what is the best (and easiest) way to do that?

On Windows I know that wstring points to UTF16 data, so I can create a simple std::u16string_view which uses the same data (no conversion).
But on Linux wstring is usually UTF32...
Is there a way to do that without macros and without things like assuming sizeof(wchar_t) == 2 => utf16?

Comment: If you're on not-Windows, shouldn't you be using `std::cout` and `std::string`, not `std::wcout` and `std::wstring`? That is, shouldn't the conversion be to UTF-8, which is ubiquitous on not-Windows platforms?

Comment: He's probably manipulating data generated by Windows applications and generated for Windows applications on a Linux server or something like that.  edit: ah, he's working with BMP strings.  There's your reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I convert wstring to u16string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734715/how-can-i-convert-wstring-to-u16string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the C++20 standard that converts `wchar_t` to `char32_t` and back. After all, `wchar_t` is [supposed to be](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#5) large enough to contain *any* supported code point.

And indeed everywhere Unicode above U+FFFF is supported, `wchar_t` is 32-bit, except on Windows (and in Java, but that's irrelevant). So yes, even today working with Unicode in a portable way is problematic, and `sizeof(wchar_t)==2` or `#ifdef _WIN32` both sound like legitimate workarounds.

Having said that, `wcout` still seamlessly works with `wchar_t` on all platforms regardless of the underlying encoding.

It is only if you *cut* wstrings or work with individual code points *and* you want to support code points beyond the basic plane, *then* you need to take surrogate pairs into account (which is pretty easy still, 0xD800–0xDBFF = first pair, 0xDC00–0xDFFF = second pair, don't cut in between).

Comment: I think it's also important to note that `char32_t` only represents a code point and not a grapheme. If you need to work with actual rendered graphemes that requires a specialized library. This is complicated... just a wee bit.

Comment: Yes, Unicode also has c̮oͣm̥bͮi̪n̆ìnͨǵ čh̎a͏r̷a͍c̘t́èr̗sͥ...

Comment: I did it now with your workaround... Not nice but it works :-)